# Angular 2 automatically block ui for each http request

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, blockui

I am using angular 2. I need to block UI on every HTTP request (get, post, ...) but I need it done automatically not manually by calling start before HTTP request begin and stop at the end.

For angular 1.x there is [plugin](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) that does it.

can anyone guide me?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock UI". What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: lock UI ->> block UI : check [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) . when submitting a form or any other API call i need to block to UI to prevent User from clicking button again and again

Answer (score 0):

Yes by implementing a canDeactivate guard in your component.
Follow the documentation, they explain the [way to achieve this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-deactivate-guard)

Hope it's help.

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't find any relation between your link and my question. can you describe more?

Comment: there's no link indeed. Your question is largely related to all httpClient I/O, and the canDeactivate is specifically related to exiting a route (either by using a promise wwhich would use an httpClient, or not)